# Concatenate arguments to the end of a script within Visual Basic using MacScript

Tags: shell, excel, vba

I am trying to run a script that requires arguments, and cannot figure out how to concatenate the name of the script with the arguments.  I am using Visual Basic for Excel 2011 and I am trying to run the script using MacScript. For example my script is called `do_a_bunch_of_stuff.sh`  To run the script, I need to pass a couple of variables (arguments); e.g. `string1` and `string2`.  If I use the following script in VB, things work fine:

`MacScript ("do shell script ""/Users/mikesmith/Desktop/directory2/do_a_bunch_of_stuff.sh string1 string2"""`

However, I need to pass `string1` and `string2` from other subroutines in my VB program.  So, I want to define two variable that I assign different and changing values.  So, I've tried the following:

```
DIM variable1, variable2 as STRING

variable1 = string1

variable2 = string2

MacScript ("do shell script ""/Users/mikesmith/Desktop/directory2/do_a_bunch_of_stuff.sh variable1 variable2"""
```

which doesn't work.  I've also tried defining the entire string within the quotes as a single string where I concatenated the path, file name, and arguments together. That doesn't work either.

Any suggestions?  I appreciate any help ...

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate strings in VB and VBA should be done with `&`

like this:

```
"do shell script ""/Users/mikesmith/Desktop/directory2/do_a_bunch_of_stuff.sh """ & variable1 & " " & variable2
```

you also can do it in multy step, like this:

```
Dim command, script as String
script = """/Users/mikesmith/Desktop/directory2/do_a_bunch_of_stuff.sh"""
command = "do shell script"
command = command & " " & script & " " & variable1 & " " & variable2
```

You also should close the parentheses like this:

```
MacScript(command)
```